# Tool for online source compilation?

Tags: compiler

I'm developing a mobile app that has tons of art, ~500MB.

Every change the client needs to implement takes a lot of time for my upload to finish, and it's taking forever.

I was wondering if there is a tool that compiles the uploaded code and creates the version ready to download.

I've read that Assembla has a "deploy" functionality, but I have no idea if that is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can't you provide a Setup + e.g. a ZIP file for the art?

Comment: Not following you, my app is made using AS3, and deployed as an Air app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe 'Assembla' is not something that can help you. As you are aiming to compile the Mobile Application (probably android or windows), it is necessary to have SDK to compile the code which makes your search difficult.

If you are required to frequently deploy the changes, I would suggest to have one development environment (virtual machine sort of thing) at client side only (if client agrees) and have it deployed from there.